# Як перекласти "вникать" з російської? Може "розібратися"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

r2u.org.ua не дає нормальних перекладів, на мою думку:

[вникать](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

Контекст: коли хочу у чомусь розібратися. Як і сказав у заголовку. Якщо хтось знає інший контекст, хай наведе.
"Давай розберемося. Давай заглибимося. Давай удамося?"

Ось ще спроби знайти розв'язок самостійно:
[РОЗІБРАТИСЯ](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F)
[ЗАГЛИБИТИСЯ](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F)
[УДАТИСЯ](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%A3%D0%94%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%AF)

І якщо хтось, знову ж таки, вважає якийсь з наведених варіантів нормальним, хай не соромиться висловити свою думку.

Comment: А чому _вдаватися (у суть, у подробиці тощо)_ не підходить?

Comment: Давай розберемося. Давай заглибимося. Давай удамося?

https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F

https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F

https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%A3%D0%94%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%AF

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості вимагають, щоб запитання про переклад містило: (1) пояснення **своїми словами** іншомовного слова; (2) **контекст**, в якому автор збирається використовувати перекладене слово; (3) продемонструвати власну спробу знайти відповідь і (4) пояснити, чим са́ме знайдені варіанти не підходять. Запитання, які не відповідають цим умовам, змушують інших «вгадувати», чого саме хоче автор, і тому заважають надавати точні відповіді.

Comment: Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).

Comment: Будь ласка, наведіть контекст, в якому ви шукаєте переклад. В такому вигляді ваше запитання не несе користі для майбутніх відвідувачів.

Comment: Чи не могли б ви навести фразу російською? Чи декілька?

Comment: @Kosarar, я правильно розумію, що Ви шукаєте переклад саме для доконаної форми (наприклад, «давайте вникнем»)?

Comment: @Sasha Не обов'язково. Розбиратимемося завтра. Але дякую за слушне запитання-уточнення.

Answer (score 2):

В словниках з [перекладів](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) наданих Вами в питанні найбільш зустрічається слово ***"вникати"***, але якщо воно Вам не подрбається можемо підібрати синонім.

В словнику синонімів Полюги є декілька синонімів до слова ***"вникати"***

> (намагатися розібратися в чомусь невідомому) *вглиблюватися, входити*, розм. *докопуватися.*

Якщо розглянути визначення самого слова ***"вникати"*** з СУМ-20

> ***[Вникати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=15342&page=506)***  а́ю, а́єш, недок., ***вникнути***, ну, неш, док., у що. Старатися, намагатися зрозуміти суть чого-небудь,
>   ***розібратися*** в чому-небудь; ***вдумуватися***.

На мою думку, цілком можливий варіант використання слова ***"розібратися"***, адже це і буде ***"вникнути"***

А також декілька синонімів до слова ["розібратися"](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F)

> розуміти що і без додатка (правильно сприйняти зміст, значення, суть
>   чого-небудь), збагнути, вбагнути *розм.*, унтути *розм.*, утямити
>   *розм.*, зметикувати *розм.*, уторопати *розм.*, розторопати,  зміркувати *діал.*, розкусити *розм*.